# Protractor not passing my tests without the done() method

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am actually finishing the unit tests of my Angular app. I am currently working on E2E tests using Protractor and Jasmine. Unfortunately, I have the following problem:

I did loads of research online  such as http://ramonvictor.github.io/protractor/slides/#/1 and I clearly never see the use of the "done" callback to launch tests.

This first test goes on the createUser page and makes sure that the user tab attribute is set to **active**. It passes ONLY if I use the done method, which I should not use.

```js
'use strict';

var UserCreate = require('./page-objects/userCreate.pageObjects');

describe('on init', function () {

    beforeEach(function() {
       var rootUrl = browser.baseUrl + '/#/users/create';
       browser.driver.get(rootUrl);
    });

    it('should set the user tab active', function(done) { // DONE callback
        UserCreate.tabs.getAttribute('class').then(function(value) {
            expect(value).toEqual('active');
            done(); // calling callback
        });
     });
 });
```

If I repeat the same test without using done(), the test passes even if this time, I want it to **fail**.

```js
'use strict';

var UserCreate = require('./page-objects/userCreate.pageObjects');

describe('on init', function () {

    beforeEach(function() {
       var rootUrl = browser.baseUrl + '/#/users/create';
       browser.driver.get(rootUrl);
    });

    it('should set the user tab active', function() {
        UserCreate.tabs.getAttribute('class').then(function(value) {
            expect(value).toEqual('activeWRONG');
        });
     });
 });
```

It only fails if I use the done callback.

Here is my config file:

```js
 /* conf.js */
'    use strict';

exports.config = {
rootElement: '#myApp',
directConnect: true,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1
},
framework: 'jasmine',
// specs: ['./*.spec.js'],
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001',
defaultTimeoutInterval: 0000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
},
suites: {
    wip:        './userCreate.spec.js',
    all:        './*spec.js'
},
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get('http://localhost:9001/#/');
    element(by.id('ld-link-login')).click();
    browser.sleep(500);

    element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('test');
    element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('test');
    element(by.id('nv-login-submit')).click();

    return browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return /dashboard/.test(url);
        });
    }, 10000);
}
};
```

I am having asynchronous problems in deeper tests with the use of done everywhere, so I want to fix this before continuing my tests.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

Protractor version:  ./node_modules/.bin/protractor --version gives Version 3.2.2

userCreate.pageObjects :

```js
'use strict';

 module.exports = {
    tabs: element(by.id('cc-tab-user'))
  };
```

Comment: Can you upgrade to Jasmine2?

Comment: I checked out via jasmine.version and my version of Jasmine is 2.4.1.

Comment: Ya but your config says `jasmine`, change it to `framework: 'jasmine2',` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Gunderson nope, jasmine refers to jasmine2 in the modern protractor.

Comment: Could you also post 2 things: protractor version and the contents of `userCreate.pageObjects` page object? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I  just edited my post with protractor version and my UserCreate object.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour. If you don't ask for the `done()` function, jasmine will consider your test as synchronous and finish without waiting for the promise to be resolved. 
When you ask for it, your test became asynchronous, and will fail if `done()` hasn't been called before the timeout ( 5 seconds by default)
See: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support for more info.

Comment: That's not expected with Protractor - it patches Jasmine to be asynchronous so each spec/test has it's own controlFlow and triggers an event when that queue is empty.  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the way you are defining the Page Object leading into the problem with the promise resolution order. Follow the [style guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#page-objects) and change it to:

```
var UserCreatePage = function() {
  this.tabs = element(by.id('cc-tab-user'));
};

module.exports = UserCreatePage;
```

Usage:

```
'use strict';

var UserCreatePage = require('./page-objects/userCreate.pageObjects');

describe('on init', function () {
    var userCreatePage;

    beforeEach(function() {
       var rootUrl = browser.baseUrl + '/#/users/create';
       browser.driver.get(rootUrl);

       userCreatePage = new UserCreatePage();
    });

    it('should set the user tab active', function() {
        userCreatePage.tabs.getAttribute('class').then(function(value) {
            expect(value).toEqual('activeWRONG');
        });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your anwer again. I modified my UserObject structure as you said but I still have the exact same problem. The only difference compared to your code is the "new" keyword to instanciate the object (error without it).  My test does not get executed without the done method but it still works when I use it. I really feel desperate about all of this.. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: @XimaBrabTobra the theory was such a good fit for this problem! :) Are you sure you have the page object defined as `function()` and calling `new()` only inside the actual test? Thanks.

Comment: This looks right and should work unless you have another underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can happen if your test creates a parallel TaskQueue in your test's Control Flow. For [what done() is for and how to use it ( protractor, jasmine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281591/what-done-is-for-and-how-to-use-it-protractor-jasmine/42355480#42355480) I wrote a few examples of tests giving inconsistent results because of this.

To figure out if this is your problem, you can print out the control flow at various points in your test:

```
console.log(protractor.promise.controlFlow().getSchedule(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that you use the `then()` to pass `value` towards your `expect`-statement.
`then()` creates a new async-task, which is dropped as subtask. As result of this, your `it` first finishes with result = success and then your expect-statement gets executed.
It's documented in the [Promise/ControlFlow documentation of Selenium](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html).

As `expect()` already unwraps/resolves a promise, there is no need for `then()` in your case.

With your `done` it works, because you take control of the execution and prevent `it` to continue/finish before your `then()` is  finished.

Try this:

```
'use strict';

var UserCreate = require('./page-objects/userCreate.pageObjects');

describe('on init', function () {

    beforeEach(function() {
       var rootUrl = browser.baseUrl + '/#/users/create';
       browser.driver.get(rootUrl);
    });

    it('should set the user tab active', function() {
        expect(UserCreate.tabs.getAttribute('class')).toEqual('activeWRONG');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the control flow which is not running properly in your code . The control flow is based on the concept of tasks and task queues. Tasks are functions that define the basic unit of work for the control flow to execute. Each task is scheduled via ControlFlow#execute(), which will return a ManagedPromise that will be resolved with the task's result.

The following should work.

```
let UserCreate = require('./pageobject.page.js');
describe('should navigate to url', function () {
    beforeEach(function() {
      url = `${browser.baseUrl}/#/users/create`;
      browser.driver.get(url);
    });
    it('should set the user tab active', function() {
   expect(UserCreate.tabs.getAttribute('class')).toEqual('activeWRONG');
    });
});
```